# Where should I put global application setup routines in Django?

Tags: django

In a large Django project, I have several evil monkey-patching hacks to execute at application startup time. However, I don't quite see a correct place for such hackery: neither `urls.py` nor `settings.py` nor `manage.py` seem fit for this. Where would you recommend I put those?

Answer (score 1):

In python you will always come across initialization. That's why its always better to use init for initialization. Even in django when you create a project it must have an init.py in it.
I usually put all my initialization in `__init__.py` its a safe and clean way. You can do the same rather than create another initialization module.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a good answer to this question at the moment. There's a Summer of Code project at the moment to rewrite the app loading process, which hopefully will include hooks for initialization code.

In the meantime, I think the best place for this is in urls.py. The admin application and Haystack both do it there, and it seems a good pattern.